# TypeScript and systemjs circle dependency

Tags: javascript, module, typescript, commonjs, systemjs

I have a problem with circle dependencies of modules:

even.ts

```
import { Odd } from './odd';

export class Even {

    log(){
        return console.log(Odd);        
    }  
}
```

odd.ts

```
import { Even } from './even';

export class Odd extends Even{

  log(){
        return console.log(Even);       
    }  

}
```

Config:

```
System.config({
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  baseURL: '/',
  transpiler: 'typescript'
});

System.import('even.js').then( a => console.log(a));
```

I tried to use requre.js but it can't resolve circle dependencies. In systemjs documentation [is written that it can resolve circle depedencies](https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es6-module-loader/blob/v0.17.0/docs/circular-references-bindings.md) but it doesn't work. The exception is `Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined` in `__extends` function.

Maybe it is better to Use CommonJS, but as I know I cant use module paths from root as I can do it in AMD and SystemJS.

Comment: This example seems a bit contrived.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @dustmouse I have two classes in two different files, The second extends the first while the first in one particular method returns an instance of the second. I can't join them in one file. It is a circle dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to fix it then doing

`System.import('./odd')
   .then(() => System.import('./even'))
   .then(a => console.log(a));`

will work.

The issue happens using both TypeScript and Babel and seems to be due to the way that they implement class inheritance in ES5 (via their _extends and _inherits methods in the transpiled code). These methods rely on the module containing the superclass to have been fully executed, however SystemJS does not know this and so it is not executing the modules in the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to resolve this is to think more in terms of modules, rather than adhering to the patterns found in C# or Java (of having one class per file).

If your `Odd` and `Even` classes are inextricably linked, place them both in the same module (file). You can't use one without the other in the set up you describe, so why force a second HTTP request.

Alternatively, re-visit your inheritance hierarchy... perhaps you have chosen the wrong base class if the base class needs to know about one of its specialisations. Maybe you are missing the true base class that both `Odd` and `Even` should extend, or maybe you could share an interface rather than a base class.

Another possibility is that you should be using delegation rather than inheritance in this case, or maybe you should be asking for the instance from a factory.

While circular dependency management sounds like a good feature, you can always solve the problem without it by going back to OOD and SOLID principles.

Comment: Yes, I thought about it, but it is imposible to add them into one file because there are a lot of another classes that would be needed to be added. In my app Even is so to say an abstract class that has methods that transforms `this` to some specific context. The contexts in their turn inherits the abstract class because each of them can be transformed to other contexts